# Grouping together in HTML similar rows of a MySQL table

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table, sql-order-by

I have a MySQL database table where I save the feedback (column '**feed**') from users.
They can both ask questions (**type** = que, with **ref** = 0) and reply (**type** = ans) to the posted questions.
The '**ref**' column shows the '**id**' of the question they refer to:

```
id     username     feed         type     ref
1        mr_x     question_1      que      0
2        mrs_y    question_2      que      0
3        mr_z     answer_to_2     ans      2
4        mr_z     answer_to_1     ans      1
5        mr_x     answer_to_2     ans      2
```

Now, I am trying to show this table in HTML. I would like to bring all the answers with the same 'ref' together, and show them below the question they refer to.

A PHP query using ORDER, for example:

```
"SELECT * FROM feedback ORDER BY ref ASC";
```

doesn't work here.

My desired output in HTML would be:

```
mr_x     question_1      que      0
mr_z     answer_to_1     ans      1
mrs_y    question_2      que      0
mr_z     answer_to_2     ans      2
mr_x     answer_to_2     ans      2
```

I probably need to count all the answers with the same '**ref**', and build a rowspan.
Has anybody ever had a similar challenge?

Comment: So... pretty much like a threaded forum then?

Comment: Yes. But I have built it minimally...as you can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query will return the records from the `feedback` table ordered by the parent `id`, with the record from the parent thread appearing before the children.

```
SELECT f.*
FROM feedback f
ORDER BY CASE WHEN f.ref = 0 THEN f.id ELSE f.ref END,
         f.id
```

**Explanation:**

The `ORDER BY` uses two criteria for ordering.  First, it orders by the `id`, when the `ref` be zero (indicating a parent thread), or the `ref` when it is not zero, indicating a child thread.  Then, to place the parent thread before the children, it orders next by the `id`.  This works, because a parent thread will always have an `id` which is less than its children.

Comment: @Alex This query should basically work.  If you have any other needs, let me know I can update.

Comment: Tim, great solution. I did not know you can use THEN and ELSE in ORDER.

Comment: LOL...neither did I ;-P